# How do I echo something while making sure the PHP inside of the echo executes?

Tags: php, escaping, echo

Sorry, really bad at explaining myself sometimes. Why don't I start from the beginning.

I have this code:

```
Posted Under <span class="cat-name">
<?php 
   $category = get_the_category();
   echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?>
```

I'd like to make sure there's actually something in $category[0]->cat_name before posting it. So I decided to do an if\isset statement:

```
<?php 
if (isset($category[0]->cat_name)) echo // This is where I'd put the above code. ?>
```

I'm just not totally sure how to do it, obviously. I know I'd have to escape the quotes, but even then it doesn't work. Here's what I've tried:

```
<?php if (isset($category[0]->cat_name))
     echo "Posted Under <span class=\"cat-name\">
     <?php 
        $category = get_the_category();
        echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></span>" 
     ?>
```

But no luck. Any ideas? Is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mix HTML and PHP code by spanning the `if()` across `<?php ... ?>` blocks. I'll use a colon instead of braces for readability.

```
<?php
    $category = get_the_category();
    // let's be extra safe
    if (isset($category[0]->cat_name)):
?>
    Posted Under <span class="cat-name">
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($category[0]->cat_name) ?>
    </span>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: You can combine the multiple `isset()` calls into one, eg `isset($category, $category[0], $category[0]->cat_name)`. Also, be careful with the short open tag, it may not be enabled on the OP's server

Comment: @Phil - Thanks for the `isset()` tip. My understanding is that `<?=` is not considered a short open tag. We use it but never use `<?`.

Comment: `<?=` requires short open tags to be enabled. To be extra safe, you should use `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($category[0]->cat_name) ?>`

Comment: This worked great. I guess I was originally struggling with the structure. Thanks for posting and helping out.

Comment: @Phil - Done. I've never had to deal with not having short open tags so I cannot confirm, but I changed it to be sure I don't trip anyone up. :)

Comment: @David - Accepted. Thanks. Sorry, new here :)